# Pseudo-3D Geometric Forms

Tags: adobe-photoshop

While putting to practice everything I've learned in this meanwhile regarding art restoration/enhancement I've got this one so destroyed due to consecutive JPEG compressions from multiple sources that I just can't save the background.

But before I can replace it I must ask how could I reproduce this polygon:

[image]

It has some pseudo-3D appearance with 3 distinct colours, inside, outside and the borders. The shape appears 4 times in the picture, at different parts (you can see a blue shine of a second instance close to this brownish-orange one) and with different positions, so I must be able to adjust this... extrusion? E.g: the blue one nearby has both the "hole" and the darker area turned right, down inclined. Theoretically, I believe it should suffice to duplicate and rotate, but who knows...

Additionally, it also has this spiky shine behind with two distinct colours with a tiny fade when they change. If they could emit light over the main image — which I already finished the stressful selection (so many curves... >.<) — it would be awesome, but not entirely required.

Problem is I have no idea how could I do that. In past, I had very bad experiences with Photoshop's way of dealing with shapes. Back in the day, I had to make the shape with the correct dimensions right at the first try because the edges became blurry after Free Transforming.

Of course, that certainly was just me knowing less than I know today but, in any event, I thought for the best to ask first how could I do that.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can we see the other shapes? Perhaps it's not worth doing it in 3D, depending on how the others look like

Comment: They're all the same, only changing colours and rotation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you asked for Photoshop, but in my opinion it would be much easier in to create such a pseudo-3D shape in Adobe Illustrator, by using its Live Paint functionality.

It's easier because all you need to do is draw lines with strokes - using the raster image to trace over the top. Closed shapes aren't required. Also, there's no messing around with shape layers like in Photoshop.

Then you can turn it into a Live Paint object. And fill the segments using the Live Paint Bucket, holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> to sample the colours from the raster image with the eyedropper.

Example - here I'm halfway through colouring it.

[image]

When you have finished you can change the stroke colour or remove the stroke entirely.

The beauty of this is that it's all vector. You can even place the finished AI in Photoshop, and when you resize it will not suffer from quality degradation.

[image]

Another possibility is to make a 3d extrusion in Illustrator, using a heptagon, with a thick stroke.

[image]

Then Expand the Appearance, ungroup, and fill the different segments with the required colours.  Finish by drawing a blue shape and send to the bottom of the stack, then add additional paths for the inside corners, and fill as required.

[image]

Comment: Sigh... I give up. Could you detail the second step some more? I never used Illustrator before so, even though I found out that "3D Extrusion" is a Filter and that "Expand the Appearance" means "click the three dots (:P), I couldn't continue after that.

Comment: And since this seems this second example will allow me to create shapes with the correct proportions, what do I do after that? Just open the file within Photoshop? Also, I have the feeling that I'll have to repeat the process again and again for each rotation, right? Because the... "inner walls" disappear every change I make to the angles, but they return as soon as I change a little bit the Perspective.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto To expand click *Object > Expand Appearance*.  Yes, you can import AI files into Photoshop as a Smart Object. Not sure what you mean about the inner walls disappearing.  If you mean you can't see them distinctly, it dosn't really matter, as they are still there. I added a second light source in the 3d extrude just to make them more visible.

Comment: @BrunoAugusto After you have expanded, click *Edit > Ungroup* repeatedly until there are no more groups left to ungroup (the option will become greyed out).. To fill a shape, select it using the Selection Tool (V), and change the fill attribute in the tool bar along the top.

Comment: Right... I somehow managed to get closer to yours, except yours is deeper, apparently, because of the **Extrusion Depth**, even though I set it to 60pt like your image. Now I need help with the internal lines because it seems I need to delimit their rectangular area to pain/fill only inside them, without bleed to the closest "interior wall". Last but not least, I think I managed to get what the inner shape would do by hiding its layer (which was blocking my way to fill the interior, that's why I said they were disappearing)

Comment: @BrunoAugusto well, yes. The extrusion depth setting would depend on the size of the image. If yours differs in size, you'll need to use different settings.  The internal lines were simply made as filled shapes made using the Pen Tool.

Comment: Alright, I guess [I did it](https://imgur.com/mkkPUxQ). If that was easier or not it's up for debate (>.< ) but I could notice from the moment I ungrouped the 3D effect that I won't be able to reuse for the other sizes and rotations, right?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto right. But now you know how to do it, second time will be much easier!!  It's  easy enough to do 3d extrusions and rotations, but modifying them is what takes time. Of course, once you have expanded the effect, it's no longer a live 3D effect.  However you could keep a copy of the live 3D object before you expanded it, in order to create more modified copies from it. Glad it worked out for you in the end!

Comment: @BrunoAugusto to modify an existing (unexpanded) 3d object, select it, and open the Appearance panel and click on the 3D Extrude and Bevel fx, then hit the preview option, and you can change the rotation.

Comment: Something I forgot to ask that I only realized when changing the colour scheme. How could I add lines to the external sides? I tried using this Pen Tool like for the internal sides but [it didn't go on the vertices](https://imgur.com/a/QIbAHy8).

Comment: @BrunoAugusto I wouldn't use a path with a stroke. Instead I would create filled shapes with the pen tool instead, or at least begin with a stroke and expand it to a fill, then add anchors, and modify the corner end. [See example](https://imgur.com/a/yIkMc70)

Comment: That was much easier but I noticed i'd have to eyeball the width, right? Os there is a way to make it 1,5pt? Maybe... 0,75 on each side?

Comment: @BrunoAugusto - you don't have to eyeball it if you start with a stroked path, expand it to a fill, and then add anchors and reposition to modify the corner

Comment: Sorry, I really tried but I don't know what that means. When I try to add these anchors around the initial line, thinking I could simply distort it (closely to PS Free Transform) it shows me an error saying "use the anchor tool on segments of path". When I finally figured out what that means, I started from the ending anchor, like I did when eyeballing, and started following the curvature of the shape. But whenever I click to add the anchor it changes the layer with right side of the shape.